# NotSupportedError when wrapping key in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, encryption, rsa, webcrypto-api

below is a very simple test that generates two keys, then tries to wrap one using the other. the 'wrapKey' call in Internet Explorer 11 throws 'NotSupportedError', I'm at a loss as to what exactly it's referring to/complaining about.

Tips/suggestions would be very welcome! According to the documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn302337%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the algorithm to use for wrapping (RSA-OAEP) should be supported... and I don't quite understand the "The wrapKey method protects key material in a JSON Web Key (JWK) structure encapsulated with JSON Web Encryption (JWE). Specifically, the key material of key is encrypted using a randomly-generated content encryption key, which in turn is encrypted with keyEncryptionKey using the specified keyWrappingAlgorithm." - sounds like it's talking about something done behind the scenes/under the covers that I theoretically shouldn't need to worry about in my calling code?

```
var rsaOaepAlgo = { name: "RSA-OAEP",
                    modulusLength: 2048,
                    hash: { name: 'SHA-256' },
                    publicExponent: new Uint8Array([0x01, 0x00, 0x01]) }
var aesCbcAlgo = {  name: "AES-CBC",
                    length: 128 }

var p = webcrypto.subtle.generateKey(
                rsaOaepAlgo,
                true,
                ["wrapKey", "unwrapKey", "encrypt", "decrypt"]
        )
return webcrypto.promisify(p)
.then(function(generatedWrapKey) {
    console.log('generated wrap key')
    keyToUseForWrapping = generatedWrapKey
    p = webcrypto.subtle.generateKey(aesCbcAlgo, true, ["encrypt", "decrypt"])
    return webcrypto.promisify(p)
})
.then(function(importedKey) {
    console.log('imported key to wrap successfully')
    keyToUseForEncryption = importedKey
    console.log(keyToUseForWrapping.publicKey.algorithm)
    console.log(keyToUseForEncryption.algorithm)
    console.log('attempting to wrap the key')
    p = webcrypto.subtle.wrapKey(keyToUseForEncryption, keyToUseForWrapping.publicKey, rsaOaepAlgo)
    return webcrypto.promisify(p)
})
```

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: Ended up utilizing Artem's handy project on github: see https://github.com/vibornoff/webcrypto-shim

Comment: Ok, I also testet that project but it does not work with AES-KW that I am needing.